# Can similar inductor value be used?

Tags: pcb-design, inductor, surface-mount

I found a schematic online of a 433mhz receiver which I am trying to replicate.
1 component is an inductor 16.6nh smd. However because I cannot find that exact value I was thinking to use an inductor with similar value 16nh.

Would it work or not?

Comment: The error tolerance is significant to tuning error frequency while a trace is < 1 nH /mm added

Comment: Put two in series.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Tony what do mean? I didnt understand sorry

Answer (score 0):

Adding 2 in series, sum 16.6nH or the double in parallel(33.2nH and 33.2nH) will work. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Tip: 'H' for *henry* as defined in SI standards. Also 'Hz' for *hertz* in your question. SI units named after a person have their symbols capitalised but are lowercase when spelled out. 'V' for volt, 'A' for ampere, 'K' for kelvin, 'Ω' (capital omega) for ohm, etc. Meanwhile 'k' is for kilo. Capitals matter!